# how to link jdbc server to another PC

Tags: java, sql-server

here my problem, I want to connect my java program to my sql server and access it by client PC without creating shortcut on the client PC. is it possible to do? I search many time but I didn't get the answer.

here is my code for connecting to the server but using only the server PC not the client.

```
 Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://serverPC:1433;databaseName=users;user=sa;password=test";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

is it possible to put in my code like

```
Class.forName("//serverPC:com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://serverPC:1433;databaseName=users;user=sa;password=test";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

by the way, using my java program when I compile it and create shortcut in the clientPC its working fine but recently I'm having a problem that the shortcut can't detect the file but when the server is rebooted the shortcut of the program works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its now working fine, the culprits why I can't connect to the server without using the shortcut is the lib folder because it contains the sqljdbcx.x file that connects to the serverPC. all I have to do is copy all the files on dist folder so it will connect properly without error.

here is the screen shot of error.
without lib folder. (error)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nF2AL.jpg)

with lib folder. no error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MCCq.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

`Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"‌​);` loads the Driver class from the classpath and has nothing todo with the Connection.

if the SQL-Server listen on the external IP address, it should work with:

```
 Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
 String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://serverPC:1433;databaseName=users;user=sa;password=test";
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

Make sure that the jar containing the Driver class is in the classpath of yor application.